# How to fetch online friends - facebook graph api

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a game for the iPhone and needed to get the friends that are online in a persons friends list..I have only been able to get the friends and their IDs. using this

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Any code would be helpful
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no api available for iPhone to that. You can only get friends list.

Comment: Damn that sucks..any way to get around it?

Comment: I have the list of user's friends. But i wan't to display only those friends who are online in Facebook. is this possible??